# Laravel Sql union of request in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to loop some sql request and create an union of all of them. I did that :

```js
$res = Media::where('position', "");
 foreach ($formatsQuery as $frmQ) {
    foreach($formats as $frm) {
        if(strcmp($frmQ, $frm)==0){
           echo $frm;
           $res = Media::where('position', $this->translateFormatToPosition($frm, $deviceQuery))->inRandomOrder()->first()->union($res);
       }
     }
  }

return $res->get();
```

I tried many thigs but it keeps failing cause of different error such as nested request or undefined variable. Any idea how to write this code? Especially how do I declare $res, cause If it has Null value, then I have an `Error: Call to a member function union() on null`

Comment: You should give your variables meaningful names and use `strcmp` with [strict comparison](https://www.php.net/strcmp).

Comment: well names are meaningful and I don't understand what you mean by strcmp with strict comparison...

Comment: I think you're applying the union to a result (which is not available, thus `null`), instead of a query. You can only union queries, not results. Strict comparison is when you use `===` instead of `==`. Especially the `str*` functions need that, because they often return a pointer (integer) **or** a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a collection and push inside it.

```js
$res = collect([]);
      $notFound = collect([]);
      foreach ($formatsQuery as $frmQ) {
        foreach($formats as $frm) {
          if(strcmp($frmQ, $frm)===0){
            try {
              $media = Media::with('ad')->where('format', $frm)->inRandomOrder()->firstOrFail();
              $res->push($media);
            } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
              $notFound->push($frm);
            }
          }
        }
```